# Supressing crash dialog in OSX

Tags: macos, crash-reports

We have a background process that scans 3rd party plug-ins and we don't 
won't the crash messages to be shown.

We can't control the machine in which our app is running so we can't use

```
   defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType server
```

Is there a way for us to hide this annoying messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to suppress crash reports for a process, you can do so by clearing the task's exception ports:

```
kern_return_t kret = task_set_exception_ports(
        mach_task_self(),
        EXC_MASK_ALL | EXC_MASK_CRASH,
        MACH_PORT_NULL,
        0,
        0);
```

Preventing the crash in the first place is obviously preferable, though. :)

Comment: Works great! it even removed the "Restore Window" messages from Lion, 10x!